# Trigger to auto sync a Quote When Check box is checked

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to write a Trigger to sync a `Quote` when checkbox is checked, that check box is created as a custom field in a quote.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: You can use Process Builder for this task. Are you certain you want a trigger?

Answer (score 1):

At the Opportunity level you have a field named as `SyncedQuoteId` and if you update this field with the desired quote id, then salesforce automatically sync this quote with opportunity.

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm):

> Read only in an Apex trigger. The ID of the Quote that syncs with the
>   opportunity. Setting this field lets you start and stop syncing
>   between the opportunity and a quote. The ID has to be for a quote that
>   is a child of the opportunity.

---

Thus you want to have something like the following code in your `Quote` `after update` trigger. Let's say, API name of checkbox is `DoOpportunitySync__c`

```
List<Opportunity> oppsToSendToSync = new List<Opportunity>();
for(Quote newQuote : Trigger.new){
    Quote oldQuote = Trigger.oldMap.get(newQuote.Id);
    if(newQuote.DoOpportunitySync__c && !oldQuote.DoOpportunitySync__c){
        oppsToSendToSync.add(
            new Opportunity(
                Id = newQuote.OpportunityId,
                SyncedQuoteId = newQuote.Id
            )
        );
    }
}

update oppsToSendToSync;
```

Comment: Thanks, But it shows an error as "list is unexpected token"

Comment: did you check [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro)  to get more about triggers?